# is there any way to use onkey without a function?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to find a way to use onkey function directly with an action like:

- Forward
- Left
- Right

Like that:

```
screen.onkey(turtle.forward(50),"Up")
```

Comment: Use a lambda: `screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.forward(50), "Up")`

Comment: yes it works thank you but is there another way because I wouldn't use any function(I do it for students who doesn't know any think about functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm partial to `partial`:

```
from functools import partial

screen.onkey(partial(turtle.left, 90), 'Left')
```